# Hall Effect Sensor for Current Sensing in High DC Voltage

Tags: hall-effect

I am designing a system to sense current and voltage of a 54V, 8AH Battery. I managed to design the voltage sensor, by using a voltage divider. As for the current sensing, i will be using the Hall Effect Sensor ACS712. I am using Arduino to read the analog value of the sensed current. However, I am concerned about the load for the Hall Effect Sensor, that it will burn the Arduino since the voltage is high. Diagram below is what i have. What should I consider in order to measure 54V max, and be safe (not burn the Ardiono)? Thanks

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f31cEZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The ACS712 has 2 KV insulation between the sensed current path and the output section - you should have no fear of the 54 Volts on the current sense inputs reaching the Arduino.

Comment: You choose the load resistance to draw whatever test current you want.  By the way, you should reduce the values of R1 and R2 considerably - the Arduino ADC input impedance will affect the voltage from your voltage divider.